# Remove element from json , without adding null

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following json :

```
var json_obj:
[{"id":"7","a_id":0,"cost":"Real Cost","desc":"this a value","minage":0,"maxage":""},
{"id":"10","a_id":0,"cost":"Real Cost","desc":"other","minage":0,"maxage":""},
{"id":"13","a_id":0,"cost":"Real Cost","desc":"other","minage":0,"maxage":""}]
```

I am using this code to remove an element from it by id :

```
jQuery.each(json_obj, function(i, val) {
  if(  val.id  === 13 ) // delete index
         {
          delete json_obj[i];
                   
          }
    });
```

but it return a json with null value like this :

```
[{"id":"7","a_id":0,"cost":"Real Cost","desc":"this a value","minage":0,"maxage":""},
{"id":"10","a_id":0,"cost":"Real Cost","desc":"other","minage":0,"maxage":""},
null]
```

is there a way to return it with out the null value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
json_obj = jQuery.grep(json_obj, function(obj) {
  return obj.id != "13";
});
```

Please note that your `id` is a string `("id":"13")`

**Demo**

```js
var json_obj = [{
    "id": "7",
    "a_id": 0,
    "cost": "Real Cost",
    "desc": "this a value",
    "minage": 0,
    "maxage": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "a_id": 0,
    "cost": "Real Cost",
    "desc": "other",
    "minage": 0,
    "maxage": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "13",
    "a_id": 0,
    "cost": "Real Cost",
    "desc": "other",
    "minage": 0,
    "maxage": ""
  }
]


json_obj = jQuery.grep(json_obj, function(obj) {
  return obj.id != "13";
});

console.log(json_obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```